# PHP $_FILES Array Manipulation

Tags: php, image, file, crop, jcrop

I am using a form to upload an image. Upon image upload, we will be able to see the uploaded image. Then I used `JCrop` (http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html) to allow cropping for this image. Let's assume I only care about `JPEG` images. I am then ready to submit the form.

Upon form submission I will perform some image manipulation and crop the image. However I want to put the information for this cropped image back into the `$_FILES` array (this is a must). How would I go about manipulating this `$_FILES` array in a PHP script?

Here is what I had attempted and it would not work.

```
$upload_dir = '/Users/user/Sites/tmp/';

$file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$file_name = "cropped_".$file_name;
$tmp_name = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];

$src_file = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmp_name);

list($width,$height) = getimagesize($tmp_name);

// Creates cropped image
$tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($_POST['w'], $_POST['h']);
imagecopyresampled($tmp, $src_file, 0, 0, $_POST['x'], $_POST['y'], $_POST['w'], $_POST['h'], $_POST['w'], $_POST['h']);
$small_pic_file_path = $upload_dir.$file_name;

imagejpeg($tmp,$small_pic_file_path,85);
$message = "<img src='http://localhost/~user/tmp/".$file_name."'>";

$_FILES['image']['name'] = $file_name;
$_FILES['image']['type'] = "image/jpeg";
// unlink($tmp_name);
// if(!move_uploaded_file($upload_dir.$file_name, $tmp_name)) echo "Failure Moving Image";
$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] = $upload_dir.$file_name;
$_FILES['image']['error'] = 0;
$sizes = getimagesize($upload_dir.$file_name);
$_FILES['image']['size'] = ($sizes['0'] * $sizes['1']);
```

It is allowable to change this `$_FILES` array?

Comment: I can't see why it wouldn't be. But you can always make a copy of it an do what you want then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only changing in the global array won't work. You are just saying `$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']` will be the newly created one. But the tmp location is having same old file.

But you have to update the image in `/tmp` folder.

Get your `tmp` path and `copy` the image there.

kind of `copy($newImage, /tmp)` - get your tmp folder path from `php.ini`

Comment: Thanks! This is the solution I was looking for. I was previously using `move_uploaded_file` when I should have been using `rename` or `copy`. `move_uploaded_file` can only be applied to files that have uploaded through the POST method.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to change a superglobal you'd better copy it into another variable and after do whatever you want.

Comment: To elaborate on @Genesor, the _FILES array is generated based on your file. You are better off building your own variables:

$size = $sizes[0] * $sizes[1];

Comment: I understand it might not be the best approach but I would definitely like to edit the FILES array _if possible_. This is because some later function will process the FILES array and not whichever other variable I create. I'd like to see if solving it this way is possible, otherwise I will have to figure out where/how this other function works.

Comment: There is nothing that prevents you, if you can't do what you want without modifying $_FILES then try to modify it.